# php includes do not work

Tags: php, html, include

I'm pretty dern new to writing code, so please excuse the poor markup. I am doing my best, I assure you! And I appreciate your time very much!

I can't seem to get the PHP-include to actually include the html I'm trying to include. Ha. My goal is to have the site navigation (and eventually the footer) each exist on a single page that I can update without having to update each site page that will feature it, then I'll use the PHP-include to pull the information from that page to include it on every page I'd like to see it on.

Y'know, on the off chance that our site balloons to several thousand pages, I'd hate to have to go to every single page to update the navigation and the footer, as I could foresee that taking a considerable amount of time.

I've poked around on the net and can't seem to figure out what, exactly, is wrong. The code itself seems to be correct, the "navigation.php" is in the same location as index.php. I'm frustrated.

I've tried changing the text in the navigation.php to simply be a couple words just to make sure the information is actually being pulled, and nothing.

My server  has no problems with PHP. So... what the heck is going on?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Vices I Admire</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Courgette' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"> 
<meta name="author" content="Dave Curtis">
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="vices.css" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>

<?php include("navigation.php"); ?>
```

And the navigation.php contains this:

```
<div id="topwrapper">
<div class="info">
<p>Vices I Admire are the leading authority on alternative rock. They are also the only Denver band with a license to krill</p>
</div>
<div class="navmenu">
<div id="width">
<ul>
<li id="navname"><a href="index.html">Vices I Admire</a></li>
<li class="navli"><a href="#News">News</a></li>
<li class="navli"><a href="#Shows">Shows</a></li>
<li class="navli"><a href="#Music">Music</a></li>
<ul>
<li><a href="#Fables">Fables</a></li>
<li><a href="#VenomPride">Venom &amp; Pride</a></li>
<li><a href="#Politics">The Politics of Apathy</a></li>
<li><a href="#Planb">Plan B.</a></li>
</ul>
<li class="navli"><a href="#Video">Video</a></li>
<li class="navli"><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
<li class="navli"><a href="https://squareup.com/market/vices-i-admire-llc">Store</a></li>
<!--<li class="navli"><a href="#Photos">Photos</a></li>-->
<li class="navli"><a href="mailto:dave@vicesiadmire.com">Contact</a></li>
<li class="navli"><a href="/fun.html">Fun</a></li>
<li id="navlast"><a href="#emailtable">Join</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!--<a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>-->
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any errors in the error log? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: What does the source code delivered to the browser look like? Does it show the PHP tags?

Comment: @JayBlanchard  Well, interestingly enough, I went through and re-wrote the whole schebang and it appears to be working. I swear I adjusted the index to .php previously, but maybe that WAS the problem, in fact, I know I did, but maybe I still had the .html in there. I changed it back to .php this time and then deleted the original and, well, I think that must be what resolved it. I shoulda just kept plugging away. Thanks for taking a look, everyone!